# How can I disable the Menu control from styling itself in javascript?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, webresource.axd, aspmenu-control

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and ASP.NET 4.0 to render a Menu control as an HTML list so I can style it using CSS.  Here is the code I am using below

```
<asp:Menu ID="navlist" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal"
SkipLinkText="" ClientIDMode="Static" DataSourceID="MenuSource" 
MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" IncludeStyleBlock="False" 
StaticDisplayLevels="2">
</asp:Menu>
```

This produces the following HTML

```
<!-- URL shortened -->
<script src="/WebResource.axd?...t=634066906994188146"type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="navlist">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="link1.html">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="link2.html">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

At first glance this looks like exactly what I wanted.  However, if I open up WebResource.axd there is a whole bunch of javascript code related to the menu.  Part of this code is applying it's own inline styles to the list.  Using FireBug I can view the HTML markup after the javascript has executed and it looks something like this:

```
<div id="navlist" style="float: left;">
    <ul class="level1 static" tabindex="0" style="position: relative; width: auto; float: left;" role="menubar">
        <li role="menuitem" class="static" style="position: relative; float: left;">
            <a href="link1.html" class="level2 static" tabindex="-1">Link 1</a>
        </li><li role="menuitem" class="static" style="position: relative; float: left;">
            <a href="link2.html" class="level2 static" tabindex="-1">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

These inline styles ultimately affect the layout of my page.  I have no need for any of the scripts in WebResource.axd.  How can I prevent this script from being rendered in the final markup of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do much to change the out-of-the-box functionality of the `Menu` control. However, you could either create your own control or use the [CSS Control Adapter Toolkit](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/05/02/CSS-Control-Adapter-Toolkit-for-ASP.NET-2.0-.aspx).

Comment: Thanks David, I'll try and go in another direction

Answer (score 8):

You can tell the menu to NOT style itself if you want to just use the IncludeStyleBlock Attribute

By default its turned on "true"

```
<asp:Menu IncludeStyleBlock="False" />
```

Answer (score 5):

On your css use the !important

Comment: It's really that simple, thanks a lot for the clue! I've been struggling with the same issue for the whole day.

Answer (score 4):

I've created a custom menu (derived from System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu) and replaced the OnPreRender:

```
public class MyCustomMenu : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu
{
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Don't call base OnPreRender
        //base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
}
```

That did the trick.

Comment: I looked at dozens of solutions/suggestions but yours was the simplest and cleanest. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to override the `asp:menu` with a custom class, but still haven't learned how to simply remove all attributes from the `ul`, `li`, and `a` tags so that I could apply my own css code to a clean list.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Namespace MCO

Public Class MyCustomMenu
    Inherits Menu

        Protected Overrides Sub OnPreRender(e As EventArgs)
            ' don't use this:
            ' MyBase.OnPreRender(e)

            ' but leaving this blank produces NO rendered menu
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

---

I have also tried the jQuery method:

```
$("#navlist li,#navlist li a,#navlist ul,#navlist div").removeAttr('style');
```

But because the .net webresource is the *last* thing to run, I found that jQuery line didn't work. It *should*, but doesn't. `:(`

Comment: Consider not using the `Menu` control, and instead using a plain jQuery menu widget.

Comment: I've worked out other alternatives when all I need to do is display a menu without any filtering. There are times when I _must_ use the asp:menu control because it does security trimming by active directory role. I've tried to use jQuery to hide links by role match (or non-match) without success.

Answer (score 0):

---

I managed this by removing inline styles and changing some class names via jQuery. Of course you can re-style every element but it just produces a lot of unnecessary css code.

Use this, if you want to remove those inline styles from li, a, ul and divs:

```
$("#navlist li,#navlist li a,#navlist ul,#navlist div").removeAttr('style');
```

Second you can change those class names e.g.:

```
$("#from-this-element").removeClass(.remove-me).addClass('.new-class');
```

And I think it's the best way to use this script after the page has loaded.